# How to add multiple layers using TileLayer and TileLayer.WMS in leaflet

Tags: maps, leaflet, wms

I am new to leafletjs. I am working on a map that renders just the united states map with few layers options such as roads and major roads ecc.. I have a base layer that uses [WMS](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-wms) protocol to get the first layer's tiles with the following code:

```
L.tileLayer.wms(......)
```

Then I have another layer that comes from a different server which does not use WMS protocol. This server accepts parameters like bbox, height, width, lat, lng and few others. I can query this server for one tile at a time, so i need to provide multiple ajax calls to get multiple tiles to cover my current view and also update all layers when the map is moved.

**The problem I have is how to make both layers work together? and how to get the Bounding Box of each tile the leafletJS way? and how to continue to update all tiles on "moveend" event as the user moves the map?**

Using version 0.7.3 of leafletJS!

Thanks for your help

Comment: I am just new to this mapping business, sorry if I misled you. I removed the arcgis tag.

Answer (score 2):

There is undocumented function in `L.TileLayer` class:

```js
L.TileLayer.getTileUrl(tilePoint)
```

This function is called for each tile on a screen. It receives hash with `x`, `y` and `z` keys (tile number) and returns image URL for the tile. You can rewrite this function in your `L.TileLayer` instance:

```js
var layer = L.tileLayer(url);
layer.getTileUrl = function(tilePoint) {
    return 'http://example.com/' + tilePoint.z + '/' + tilePoint.y + '/' + tilePoint.x + '.png';
}
```

So, you don't need to track map movements, appearing and disappearing of tiles, etc.